# Angularfire2 destroy/unsubscribe Observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2

In my Ionic app I need to destroy/unsubscribe the Observable. In view I am using **Async Pipe**. I know unsubscribe is not a function of Observable but I need a way to do that. I just want when user logout or page leaves then Observable destroyed or unsubscribe.
Below is my code.

```
cartRef: AngularFireList<any>;
cart: Observable<any>;

constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.cartRef = this.db.list(`/cart/123`);
    this.cart = this.cartRef
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({
            key: c.payload.key,
            ...c.payload.val()
        }))
    );
}
```

Now when user leaves the page I want unsub that Observable

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
   // below line does not work because it is not valid subscriber
   // this.cart.unsubscribe();
}
```

Now when I logout user from Firebase then above Observable runs automatically after logout and through me a error

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /cart/123: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

That's why I was looking a way to unsub that Observable.

Comment: The async pipe [takes care of unsubscribing](https://medium.com/@nacimidjakirene/the-async-pipe-automaticaly-handle-subscribtion-for-you-and-unsubscribe-from-the-source-observable-9282f2abf474). Why do you want to do it in `ngOnDestroy`?

Comment: Actually my problem is that when I logout from Firebase then this function runs after that and through me a error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /cart/2AzJDhku1wScb4kbVITEw2: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

Comment: If you want to unsubscribe explicitely, you may need to subscribe explicitely instead of using the async pipe. I don't know if unsubscribing in `ngOnDestroy` would make a difference however; I assume that the async pipe does just that.

Comment: My requirement is that I must need an async pipe.

Comment: after logout do you stay in the same page or redirect?

Comment: no I redirect to login page. I am surprised that why above function runs after logout.

Comment: i thinks you don't need to worry about it much. may be firebase rules trigger first before your redirect.

Comment: but my App throwing error so it is no good. I need to fix.

Comment: did you set `canActivate:[AuthGuard]` on your routes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try takeUntill

firstly declare some subject

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

in observable chain it will be like this

```
.takeUntill(this.ngUnsubscribe)
```

and in you OnDestroy life hook you need to create this function

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.initUnsubscribe();
}
```

and a function for unsubscribtion

```
 initUnsubscribe(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Works for me, but ye better use Async pipe and let Angular do all magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Then you can add this to your observable:

```
.takeUntil(this.destroy$)
```